# PhoneGap Meteor iOS Push Notifications

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

I have currently used phonegap and deployed an iOS app that takes the URL of my meteor app and convert it into a "webapp" (not sure if this is accurate). However, I would like to implement remote/push notifications to Apple's servers APNS to enable the app to receive notifications, update badges etc... Are there any other means other than Urban airship?

Also, I chanced upon ObjectiveDDP, https://github.com/boundsj/ObjectiveDDP#requirements, but the tutorial is not working for me and it is really frustrating.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Phonegap team [Push Plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/3) ([on github](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/README.md)) that allows sending push notifications for Android and iOS.

The plugin can be integrated via the phonegap build site without having to use Java or Objective-C or using Java or Objective-C.

Comment: may i ask where do you invoke the push notifications from?

Comment: The notifications are pushed from a server. The code shows example of building a simple Ruby server (I think there is an example using nodejs too somewhere) which register the mobile clients on startup and push messages.

Answer (score 3):

*Here is an updated answer that works as of 12/25/14:*

Simply use the push package by raix: https://atmospherejs.com/raix/push The documentation is really good.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this one, 
https://github.com/SpaceCapsule/Meteor-phonegap-push 
I am implementing the same, 
If I am able to do so I will put the demo too 
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am able to do so for android and I am working on ios now for android [link] (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.youiest.tapmatrix) this is the link and for ios I will be putting the same.

Answer (score 0):

I just released a new package that makes it easy to integrate Meteor with Cordova (Phonegap). You can use the Cordova API, including push notifications, just like it describes in the docs.

Check out [Cordova Loader](https://github.com/andrewreedy/meteor-cordova-loader) package.

Use [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin#plugin-api)

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git`